# Named subroutines in Oniguruma regex engine?

Tags: ruby, regex, perl, pcre, oniguruma

In Perl, you can do this:

```
(?x)
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<animal>dog|cat)
)
(?&animal)
```

In Ruby (Oniguruma engine), it seems that the `(?(DEFINE...` syntax is not supported. Also, `(?&...` becomes `\g`. So, you can do this:

```
(?x)
(?<animal>dog|cat)
\g<animal>
```

But of course, this is not equivalent to the Perl example I gave above, becuase the first `(?<animal>dog|cat)` is not ignored, since there isn't anything like `(?(DEFINE...`.

If I want to define a large regex with a bunch of named subroutines, what I could once do in Perl can't be done this way.

It does seem that I could hack together a pretty awkward solution by doing something like this:

```
(?x)
(?:^$DEFINE
  (?<animal>dog|cat)
){0}
\g<animal>
```

But, that is pretty hackish. Is there a better way to do this? Does Oniguruma support a way to define named subroutines without having to try to "match" them first?

Alternatively, if there is a way to get true PCRE to work in Ruby, with `?(DEFINE...` and `(?&...` I'd take that too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a so complicated hack. Writing:

```
(?x)
(?<animal>dog|cat){0}
(?<color>red|green|blue){0}
...
your main pattern here
```

does exactly the same.

Putting all group definitions inside `(?:^$DEFINE ... ){0}` is only cosmetic.

Note that a group with the quantifier `{0}` isn't tried at all (the quantifier is taken in account first), and if in this way the named group is defined anyway, man can deduce that it isn't really a hack, but the way to do it with oniguruma.

Comment: Good answer, but I would add that the "cosmetic" form should be simply `(?: ... ){0}`.  The `^$DEFINE` part serves no purpose, and if the variable `$DEFINE` has been set, its value could be something that will break the regex.  As you said, the `{0}` provides the essential functionality; grouping is just a convenience.